# Programmatically creating aws API key and adding it to a usage plan in single function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I need to:

1. Create API keys
2. Add newly created API Keys to Usage Plans

Following the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlanKey-property), I can generate an `API key` by calling [`apigateway.createApiKey()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createApiKey-property) and then can add usage plan for that generated api key by calling another function. [`apigateway.createUsagePlanKey()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlanKey-property) seems most appropriate function for later case.

Can I perform both the functionalities in single function rather than calling two functions separately like any function that generates a new API Key and adds it a usage plan as well?

Answer (score 1):

The [ImportApiKeys API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/import-api-keys.html) allows you to both create API Keys in bulk and attach the keys to Usage Plans in the same call.

Input is a [CSV in the following format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-key-file-format.html)

```
Name,key,description,Enabled,usageplanIds
MyFirstApiKey,apikey1234abcdefghij0123456789,An imported key,TRUE,c7y23b
```

Comment: Thanks but my requirement is to create single key at a time and attaching that key to usage plan

Comment: You can create a single key with this as well. There is no minimum.

Comment: ahaan that would be cool and I can do that programmatically in nodejs, right? lemme check it out